# Shiny layout, is it possible to have a left and ride sidebarLayout in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny is it possible to have a layout like this?

[image]

I would ideally like a left and right sidebar (I have seen some solutions in `shinydashboardPlus` but this is not exactly what I am after...)

I have an app with a similar structure to this example:

```r
mychoices <- c("pick me A", 
               "pick me - a very long name here", 
               "no pick me - B", 
               "another one that is long")

ui <- 
  navbarPage(
    tabPanel("Dataset description",
    ),
    tabPanel("Data",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fluidRow(
                   column(2,
                          p(strong("Classes")),
                          actionButton(inputId = "selectall", label="Select/Deselect all",
                                       style='padding:12px; font-size:80%'),
                          br(), br(),
                          checkboxGroupButtons(
                            inputId = "classes",
                            choices = mychoices,
                            selected = mychoices,
                            direction = "vertical",
                            width = "100%",
                            size = "xs",
                            checkIcon = list(
                              yes = icon("ok", 
                                         lib = "glyphicon"))
                          ),
                   ),
                   column(6,
                          br()
                   ),
                   column(4,
                          p(strong("Controls")),
                          p("Transparency"),
                          sliderInput("trans", NULL,
                                      min = 0,  max = 1, value = .5),
                          actionButton("resetButton", "Zoom/reset plot", 
                                       style='padding:6px; font-size:80%'),
                          actionButton("clear", "Clear selection", 
                                       style='padding:6px; font-size:80%'),
                          actionButton("resetColours", "Reset colours", 
                                       style='padding:6px; font-size:80%'),
                   )
                 )
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                             tabPanel("Scatter", id = "panel1",
                                      plotOutput(outputId = "scatter")),
                             tabPanel("PCA", id = "panel2"))
               )
             ))
  )


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Ideally I would like to split the `sidebarLayout` so that one column is on the left (classes), and one on the right (controls) as when the app loads the two columns are [overlapping like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833695/stop-elements-in-a-shiny-sidebarpanel-from-overlapping-in-columns).

Any suggestions on a better an app design or solutions to this please?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at : https://rinterface.com/shiny/shinydashboardPlus/

Comment: Thanks @Waldi but already mentioned in my post I have already looked at `shinydashboardPlus` and have actually an [active post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837262/is-it-possible-to-fix-the-left-and-right-sidebars-in-shinydashboardplus-to-perma) seeking how to fix the sidebars to mimic the above. I was hoping there was an easier more elegant solution

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast... no other solution on my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Was just an idea ... so I dropped the `sidebarLayout` and added a second `sidebarPanel`. To make sure that both sidebars and the main panel fit in one row I used the `width` argument.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

mychoices <- c(
  "pick me A",
  "pick me - a very long name here",
  "no pick me - B",
  "another one that is long"
)

ui <-
  navbarPage(
    tabPanel("Dataset description", ),
    tabPanel(
      "Data",
      sidebarPanel(
        width = 3,
        p(strong("Classes")),
        actionButton(
          inputId = "selectall", label = "Select/Deselect all",
          style = "padding:12px; font-size:80%"
        ),
        br(), br(),
        checkboxGroupButtons(
          inputId = "classes",
          choices = mychoices,
          selected = mychoices,
          direction = "vertical",
          width = "100%",
          size = "xs",
          checkIcon = list(
            yes = icon("ok",
              lib = "glyphicon"
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        width = 6,
        tabsetPanel(
          type = "tabs",
          tabPanel("Scatter",
            id = "panel1",
            plotOutput(outputId = "scatter")
          ),
          tabPanel("PCA", id = "panel2")
        )
      ),
      sidebarPanel(
        width = 3,
        p(strong("Controls")),
        p("Transparency"),
        sliderInput("trans", NULL,
          min = 0, max = 1, value = .5
        ),
        actionButton("resetButton", "Zoom/reset plot",
          style = "padding:6px; font-size:80%"
        ),
        actionButton("clear", "Clear selection",
          style = "padding:6px; font-size:80%"
        ),
        actionButton("resetColours", "Reset colours",
          style = "padding:6px; font-size:80%"
        )
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great idea! Thanks so much!